# Azure logic app cannot connect to salesforce sandbox

Tags: salesforce, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which connects to a salesforce sandbox instance and do some record upsert. It was working fine till last week, suddenly logic app started showing error.

```
Session expired or invalid
```

I tried reauthorising salesforce connection. Authorisation was successful, but after i saved it will again shows following error

```
Test connection failed. Error ''
```

We contacted both azure and salesforce support as per them there is no problem on their side. Also we found that azure logic app is working with our production instances and every other sandbox instance.

So we think that issue is on this particular sandbox instance. We recently enabled communities, guest access and lightning out component on this instance, that was also long time ago. This logic app was working even after we made those change.

We do not have any other salesforce integration which uses oauth flow as azure logic app.

Is there any anyone familiar with this problem, please help us to identify the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know what's the sandbox's instance (Setup -> Company Information). Might be something related to Winter'21 preview: https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2020/08/winter-21-sandbox-preview.html. Do you have dedicated connection user? Maybe it's deactivated or maybe there are errors in login history. Does the app use OAuth2 client id and secret? were they generated in production or in a sandbox? Maybe they changed.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out be a mistake on my side.

In the documentation it says

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/salesforce/

> Salesforce session settings can block this integration. Please ensure that setting "Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated" is disabled.

Seems we enabled this feature for extra security, but we never thought it will effect the azure logic app integration.

Thanks all